# Find the total number of goats in the herd

Tags: lateral-thinking

Two brothers were herding few goats together in the woods, at a tree the herd breaks into two parts and each brother tends to one group.

Older brother says, "*Give me one goat, I will have twice as you.*"
Younger brother retorts, "*You give me one and we will be equal.*"

So what is the total herd size combined together among them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total herd size is

> $12$ goats

Let $X$ be the number of goats the older brother has, $Y$ be the number the younger brother has.

"Give me one goat, I will have twice as you."

> $X+1 = 2(Y-1)$

"You give me one and we will be equal."

> $X-1 = Y+1$

Solving we get

> $X=7, Y=5$ and $X+Y=12$

Comment: This is just a math story problem, as the solution clearly shows.